# Parse Push Notifications Android to appear once the app is opened

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I have done a lot of reading on Parse push notifications. I have push notifications working perfectly if the app is running or sitting in the background (user gets out of the app by pushing the home button or back button). I know I cannot get notifications to appear if the app has been force quit but if I close the app/force quit the app, is there a way to get the notifications to pop up the next time the app opens?

I have implemented MainApplication and made sure my manifest is correct but if the app is completely closed, then I do a push notification from Parse and then go to open the app it is as if it has not received it and never will display. Is that normal behavior?

Thanks,

Adam

Main Application

```
public class MainApplication extends Application {
private static MainApplication instance = new MainApplication();

public MainApplication()
{
    instance=this;
}
public static Context getContext()
{
    return instance;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
    //initialise whatson from parse.com
    Parse.initialize(this, "xxxxx", "xxxxx");
    PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);
    //to register device to get push notifications and register the install
    ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Log.d("com.parse.push", "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
            } else {
                Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to subscribe for push", e);
            }
        }
    });
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
}
}
```

Comment: That is a normal behaviour, when you force stop any app, it stops receiving notifications and stops working properly.

Comment: So there is no way to check if there were any notifications pushed in the time it was closed and retrieve them on opening?

Comment: You can use the broadcast receiver to save your data in shared preference or in sqlite database.

Comment: Have you considered using cloud messaging? that way you can receive notifications even if your app is not running

Comment: With parse also app can receive data when not running, but you have to save data somewhere to retrieve it later.

Comment: Thanks for the info, will look into storing the notifications to be retrieved. jirungaray, I will also investigate cloud messaging. Only wanted to use Parse as it's currently my BaaS and has got push notifications built in.